# Sublime text 3 Fira Code ligatures

Tags: sublimetext3

Accordingly [to this commit](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/pull/502), ST3 has support for Fira Code ligatures, but I still don't see any changes.
Obviously I have installed Fira code and have `"font_face": "Fira Code",` settings for this in my user settings file.

But my code still with default font, without ligatures.
How I can fix it?

[image]

Comment: First (obvious) question would be, are you running one of the dev builds, because this isn't in stable yet. Apart from that, ligatures require all of the characters that make up the symbol to share the same syntax scope, so depending on the `tmLanguage` or `sublime-syntax` of the language in question, that might be getting in the way.

Comment: Yea, I missed that, switched to 3152 and now it works.

Comment: Does this have to dev build? My version is stable 3176.

Answer (score 27):

As mentioned on https://blog.sarav.co/installing-fira-code-ligatures-sublime-text-3-mac-os/. Ligature support on Sublime Text has been enabled from version **3156+.**

#### Download Dev Version 3156

First head over to https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev and then download the latest Sublime Text dev version 3156+.

**NOTE** : Kindly note that dev versions is only available for licensed user and downloading dev version might break something.

If you have not installed Fira Code already, go to https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode and download the zip from github and extract it. You’ll find the `ttf` folder under `distr` folder. Copy all the files and paste them over under `/Users/<username>/Library/Fonts` folder.

Finally, open the installed sublime text and hit `cmd+,` you will see `Preferences.sublime-settings`. Paste the following code there.

```
"font_face": "Fira Code",
"font_options":
[
    "gray_antialias"
],
```

Thats it! Now ligatures are enabled on your system. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 16):

`Fira Code` is Light by default, you can use/modify this setting:

```
"font_face": "Fira Code Medium",
// or ** Retina, Regular, Bold...
"font_options":
[
    "gray_antialias",
    "subpixel_antialias"
],
"font_size": 13,
"line_padding_top": 1,
```

Answer (score 9):

For linux users:

Go to https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

Download and extract the zip file. 
Copy all files from `ttf` folder which is in `distr` folder to

```
/home/.local/share/fonts/
```

In Sublime open

```
Preferences-> Settings
```

and copy the following code under
Preferences.sublime-settings - User   (right side of screen, put it in 2nd row just under the {

```
"font_face": "Fira Code",

"font_options":
[
    "gray_antialias"
],
```

Now, if it still doesn't work after restarting Sublime,
enter

```
fc-cache -f
```

in terminal and restart Sublime again.

I hope this works for you as well ...

Comment: You sir are a Genius. I was looking for this same post yesterday to install in my windows, and now i needed for linux. For ubuntu, go to gedit /etc/fonts/fonts.conf and see in which folder you should place the content of the distr folder, before doing the fc-cache -f (Create a FiraCode folder, and puts all the folders inside this FiraCode dir). In my case was /usr/share/fonts/FiraCode

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions did not suffice for me on **Windows 10** (Sublime Text 3 build 3211). What made it work was:

- re-installing the font by dragging the ttf-files into the drop area in the fonts system settings of Windows 10 as shown here (sorry, German locale):

[Screenshot from the Windows 10 settings dialog for installing new fonts via drag and drop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vJpT.png)

(The installation instructions in the Fira Code repository tell you to right-click the ttf-files and select Install in the context menu. That did not suffice in my case.)

Answer (score 0):

For whoever finds this useful, following the information found [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/ligatures.html), this worked for me for Dank Mono:

```
"font_face": "Dank Mono",
"font_options":
[
    "dlig",
    "ss01",
],
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it; a link alone is not sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

It was a pain make Fira Code works in Sublime3. But i finally done. You must to download the last version of sublime first, because previous version of sublime does not support ligatures. Link [here](https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3153_x64.tar.bz2).

In addition till now this big changes is not yet the stable version of Sublime Text it's just in the Dev Build 3152 and above, so make sure you have the right version.

Then you have to go to *Preferences*->*Settings* and put:

```
"font_face" : "Fira Code"
```

Comment: This is solution is already mentioned in the question and does not solve the ligatures problem

Comment: You did not mentioned this answer. It's a different version if you look close