# Unable to Use Fira Code Font Ligature in Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7

Tags: sublimetext3

Currently I'm using Sublime Text 3 build 3207 on Windows 7. I use the same version on Ubuntu and Fira Code font ligature is working fine. Have tried many things including [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025537/sublime-text-3-fira-code-ligatures) and also have [unanswered question](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/font-ligatures-on-st-3-build-3176-in-windows-7/41858)  in Sublime Text Forum since February 2019.

Below are my current settings:

```
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
    "font_face": "Fira Code",
    "font_options":
[
    "gray_antialias"
],
    "font_size": 8,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "theme": "Monokai Classic.sublime-theme"
}
```

Is there anything I missed here?

Comment: When you start Sublime, are there any font related messages near the top of the console? Also, does adding `"directwrite"` to the `font_options` have any effect?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no any font related messages in the console, and adding `directwrite` didn't give me any luck :(

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is that ligature use is sensitive to the language being used and sometimes the syntax definition can cause them to not work as you would expect them to. Do ligatures work in plain text files?

Comment: no, it didn't work in any file

Comment: I'm not sure how else to troubleshoot this but the devs might have an idea if nobody else does. You could try pinging `@wbond` in your forum post or create an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry for forgetting to respond how I did solve this problem.
I created an issue at the forum: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sublime-text-3-build-3207-ligatures-not-working/44690. The reason why I have the problem in the first place is

> Under a blank Windows7 SP1 ligatures don’t work. Only after applying some unspecified Windows patches they work

Comment: I can confirm this. I have the same issue that ligatures don't work under a new installed Win7 SP1 system. But after apply many Windows patches and hot-fixes, and reboot the system, and the ligatures work now! BTW, ligatures not only work under sublimetext, but also work on many other editors, such as Notepad++, Code::Blocks, etc.